# Filtering by the month Name only

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have three dates in cells A1, A2 and A3. I want to take the month of each date and filter on a dataset containing multiple dates. The filter should only contain dates that are present in the month of each of the three dates in A1, A2 and A3.

For example:

A1: 01/01/2015,
A2: 01/02/2015,
A3: 01/03/2015

```
 Dataset:
 20/01/2015
 25/12/2015
 01/09/2015
 14/02/2015
 15/03/2015
 01/06/2015
```

The filter should be therefore:

```
 20/01/2015
 14/02/2015
 15/03/2015
```

My current syntax is this:

```
 Dim mon1 As String
 Dim mon2 As String
 Dim mon3 As String

 Dim a As Date
 Dim b As Date
 Dim c As Date

 a = Range("A1")
 b = Range("A2")
 c = Range("A3")

mon1 = MonthName(Month(a))
mon2 = MonthName(Month(b))
mon3 = MonthName(Month(c))

With ActiveSheet

 .AutoFilterMode = False
 .Range("A5:D5000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array(mon1, mon2, mon3), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End With
```

Unfortunately it does not seem to work though.

Comment: Doesn't `MonthName()` return the full name, while your cells contain the number of the month? Also, are your data cells formatted as Date? Otherwise Excel has problems recognizing date parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Insert a column to the right and name it Month.

   [image]
2. Put this formula `=TEXT(C6,"mmmm")` in `D6` and then use the code below

Code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim mon1 As String, mon2 As String, mon3 As String

    mon1 = MonthName(Month(Range("A1")))
    mon2 = MonthName(Month(Range("A2")))
    mon3 = MonthName(Month(Range("A3")))

    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A5:D5000").AutoFilter Field:=4, _
        Criteria1:=Array(mon1, mon2, mon3), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have adjusted the syntax slightly to include the year. But the principle is the same.